# Copy SAP HANA project from Amazon Web Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, hana, hana-studio

I have a HANA project hosted on Amazon Web Service. I also have a trial instance of HANA.

How can I copy or export my project from Amazon to the trial instance using HANA Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing and Exporting in HANA is done through Delivery Units and Packages.

You will need to create a Delivery Unit in your AWS instance, add your project to that Delivery Unit as a package.  Then you will export the Delivery Unit.

On your trial instance, you will import the Delivery Unit.

[Creating a Delivery Unit](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/hana/blog/2014/06/08/introduction-of-delivery-unit-in-sap-hana)

[Importing a Delivery Unit](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/e6/c0c1f7373f417894e1f73be9f0e2fd/content.htm)

[Maintaining Delivery Unit](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/ad/e5e9094bff4bbbbb37c06f8258046d/content.htm)